# class Androidx.legacy.widget.space not found for Passcode View

Tags: java, android, passcode

This activity was originally working but then it suddenly stopped working and it showed me this error. I'm not sure how to fix it and I don't recall removing anything from my app.gradle files but does anyone know how to solve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Below is my passcode view main activity (XML shown below with error)
''' 
    PasscodeView PasswordView;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_password_view);

    PasswordView = findViewById(R.id.PasswordView);
    PasswordView.setPasscodeLength(4)
            .setLocalPasscode("1234")
            .setListener(new PasscodeView.PasscodeViewListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFail() {
                    Toast.makeText(PasswordView.this, "Passcode do not match",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String number) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(PasswordView.this,Main2Activity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

}}
```

'''

[Screenshot of Error and XML for Password View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XohLU.png)

[1st Part of App.Gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ox9l6.png)

[2nd Part of App.Gradle (Dependencies)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAJvr.png)

Answer (score 9):

Add `androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0` in project dependencies section.

```
//app/build.gradle dependencies section

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    // Other dependencies
}
```

More Details : [AndroidX Class Mappings](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings),[AndroidX Artifact Mappings](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `androidx.legacy.widget.Space` you can just use `android.widget.Space`. Eg.:

```
<android.widget.Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:minHeight="1dp"/>
```

Comment: The replacement note can be found in the `androidx.legacy.widget.Space` comment as follows: `@deprecated Use framework {@link android.widget.Space} class instead.` https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/a9ac247af2afd4115c3eb6d16c05bc92737d6305/legacy/core-ui/src/main/java/androidx/legacy/widget/Space.java

Answer (score 3):

In your layout file, replace occurrences of androidx.legacy.widget.Space with View.

eg.

```
 <androidx.legacy.widget.Space
       android:layout_width="8dp"
       android:layout_height="1dp" />
```

Should now be

```
 <View
      android:layout_width="8dp"
      android:layout_height="1dp" />
```

Had the same issue after updating my Gradle Version.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I replaced `<Space` with `<androidx.legacy.widget.Space` and error disappeared.